# Modify Multiple Images From Console

Tags: image-processing, convert, imagemagick, mogrify

I know `convert` changes from one image format to another. `mogrify` can resize and scale multiple images also. But how can I modify all images inside a directory, including the sub-directories. Like for example change every image inside a folder and its sub-folders from one format png to another format jpg, or resize all pictures in a folder and its sub-folders to a desire one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mogrify accepts a list of files, separated by line breaks, you can do this:
`mogrify -equalize $(find -iname '*.png')`

I use equalize as an example, but the important bit is the last one.

- The file name can be any expression that prints out a list of files, i use `find -iname '*.png'` as an example. You can play around with the `find` command until it give you the list of files you want.

It's important that whatever command you put in `$()` returns a list of files with their correct path. `ls -Ra` will just return the file name. The output of `find | grep png` on the other hand looks like this:

```
./Webcam/lenovo-maverick-20110101-1.png
./lenovo-maverick-20110101-2.png
./lenovo-maverick-20110101-1.png
```

Where `.` means "the current working directory".

Comment: Why won't you use `find -exec`?

Comment: @Elazar never mind me :-) I've changed the answer completely now, there's a much easier way.

Comment: `s/$(find|grep png)/$(find -iname '*.png')/` and you're OK.

Comment: Nice. i knew how to use find but never occured to me. Thank god for Linux.

Comment: Done that, thank you very much @Elazar. As I said, it's good to play around with `find`, you can have much more granular control over what files are modified, for example, excluding all that contain "-thumbnail" or something like that.

Comment: Add quotes to make it work with spaces in filenames: `mogrify -equalize "$(find -iname '*.png')"`